# How do i group duplicate objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

Take for example this array:

```
 [{id: 0, weight: 200}
 {id: 0, weight: 200}
 {id: 1, weight: 75}
 {id: 2, weight: 5}]
```

I need to get it a result of :

```
[  {id:0, times:2},
   {id:1, times:1},
   {id:2, times:1}]
```

Comment: can you show the code where you have attempted a solution?

Comment: Is there a limited range of what the id's could be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine multiple arrays by same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039206/combine-multiple-arrays-by-same-key)

Comment: @Kadima nope the ids can be random

Comment: @NateAnderson I deleted the code already but what I tried to do was to iterate each item of the array through the same array and compare ids and push a result object into a results array.

Comment: You expected result makes no sense to me.. id:1 ? how many times... Are you saying properties of each object in the array will always be the same... . If there are more than weight and id do you need to compare all every property of an object for an equality count. Or if id:1 had weight:40 and id: 1 also has weight of 30 do you not count that as a duplicate? Or just compare on id?

Answer (score 9):

You could reduce the array into a new array with the count

```js
var arr = [
    { id: 0, weight: 200 }, 
    { id: 0, weight: 200 }, 
    { id: 2, weight: 75  }, 
    { id: 9, weight: 5   }
];

var arr2 = arr.reduce( (a,b) => {
    var i = a.findIndex( x => x.id === b.id);
    return i === -1 ? a.push({ id : b.id, times : 1 }) : a[i].times++, a;
}, []);

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Why the comma operator?

Comment: It's a return statement, so it returns anything after the last comma.

Comment: i know. But why not n?n:n; return a; <= the same but easuer to understand

Comment: Says the guy who sticks an IIFE in the middle of his code to create an unnecessary closure? Anyway, it's just a habit, could just as easily have done the assigning before the return in this case.

Comment: @adaneo touché.

Answer (score 2):

This simple reducer will return an array of arrays, each one containing all the duplicate elements in the original array.

```
function groupDuplicates(array, compareF) {
    return array.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const existingGroup = acc.find(g => (compareF(g[0], item)));
        if (existingGroup) {
            existingGroup.push(item);
        } else {
            acc.push([item])
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

Where *compareF* is your custom comparator, and should returns true if it's parameters are considered to be equal.

NOTE: In this implementation, non duplicated items will remain as the only element in their array. You may want to filter these out later, like so:

```
const duplicatesOnly = groupDuplicates(myArray, myComparator).filter(i => (i.length > 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array= [
 {id: 0, weight: 200},
 {id: 0, weight: 200},
 {id: 1, weight: 75},
 {id: 2, weight: 5}];

console.log(array.reduce((function(hash){
return function(array,obj){
 if(!hash[obj.id])
  array.push(hash[obj.id]={id:obj.id,times:1});
 else
   hash[obj.id].times++;
  return array;
  };    
})({}),[]));
```

See [Combine multiple arrays by same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039206/combine-multiple-arrays-by-same-key/45039447#45039447) for an explanation and you can try it here :http://jsbin.com/licuwadifa/edit?console.

Comment: No reason to repost your answer when you already voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @bergi its not an exact duplicate and i thought the OP might not be able to implement it for his usecase.

Comment: @Jonasw yup i did see the post that you linked to before but i didnt know how to implement it. Thank you so much!! You're a real lifesaver:)